# Flutter web does not start

Tags: flutter, web

can you help me debug?

For long time I have not tried to launch my app in web. So it is possible I made some updates/upgrades along the way. But now I am unable to start web app no debug, not release. I tried new clean project.
flutter create newone --platforms=web
cd newone
flutter run -d chrome

The window opens but "keeps loading" (forever)

see attached output from flutter run --verbose and flutter doctor -v

```
tpnsvo-Latitude-5591:~/projekty/android/newone$ flutter run --verbose
[  +75 ms] executing: uname -m
[  +45 ms] Exit code 0 from: uname -m
[        ] x86_64
[   +6 ms] executing: [/home/tpnsvo/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git -c
log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +9 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1
--pretty=format:%H
[        ] 77d935af4db863f6abd0b9c31c7e6df2a13de57b
[        ] executing: [/home/tpnsvo/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git tag
--points-at 77d935af4db863f6abd0b9c31c7e6df2a13de57b
[  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at
77d935af4db863f6abd0b9c31c7e6df2a13de57b
[        ] 2.8.1
[   +7 ms] executing: [/home/tpnsvo/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git rev-parse
--abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +5 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/home/tpnsvo/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git ls-remote
--get-url origin
[  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +118 ms] executing: [/home/tpnsvo/snap/flutter/common/flutter/] git rev-parse
--abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +9 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +78 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping
update.
[  +11 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required,
skipping update.
[ +113 ms] executing: /home/tpnsvo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +57 ms] List of devices attached
[   +5 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required,
skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required,
skipping update.
[ +114 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[ +945 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
[ +116 ms] Updating assets
[ +122 ms] Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
[  +99 ms] <- reset
[   +9 ms] /home/tpnsvo/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart
--disable-dart-dev
/home/tpnsvo/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/fr
ontend_server.dart.snapshot --sdk-root
/home/tpnsvo/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/
--incremental --target=dartdevc --debugger-module-names
--experimental-emit-debug-metadata -DFLUTTER_WEB_AUTO_DETECT=true --output-dill
/tmp/flutter_tools.GAXPLX/flutter_tool.MUEDDJ/app.dill --libraries-spec
file:///home/tpnsvo/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/librar
ies.json --packages
/home/tpnsvo/projekty/android/newone/.dart_tool/package_config.json
-Ddart.vm.profile=false -Ddart.vm.product=false --enable-asserts
--track-widget-creation --filesystem-root
/tmp/flutter_tools.GAXPLX/flutter_tools.NYUFWD --filesystem-scheme
org-dartlang-app --initialize-from-dill
build/b1b715402d823b7fd5c2b68d2edcb2ce.cache.dill.track.dill --platform
file:///home/tpnsvo/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/flutter_web_sdk/kernel
/flutter_ddc_sdk_sound.dill --sound-null-safety
[  +18 ms] <- compile org-dartlang-app:/web_entrypoint.dart
[+26751 ms] Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome... (completed in
26,9s)
[        ] Synced 28.4MB.
[        ] <- accept
[        ] Caching compiled dill
[ +911 ms] Using Chromium 97.0.4692.99 snap

[   +4 ms] executing: uname -m
[  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: uname -m
[        ] x86_64
[+1148 ms] [CHROME]:
[        ] [CHROME]:DevTools listening on
ws://127.0.0.1:38625/devtools/browser/e1dec5de-c9fb-4781-a034-d765b3b0cb5e


tpnsvo-Latitude-5591:~/projekty/android/newone$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Linux Mint 20 5.4.0-96-generic, locale
    cs_CZ.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at /home/tpnsvo/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (6 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/tpnsvo/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/tpnsvo/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_312-8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04-b07)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = /snap/bin/chromium

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
    • cmake version 3.10.2
    • ninja version 1.8.2
    • pkg-config version 0.29.1

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).

[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 3.32.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Linux (desktop) • linux  • linux-x64      • Linux Mint 20 5.4.0-96-generic
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Chromium 97.0.4692.99 snap

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score 0):

(Try to trace back the cause of the issue.
Maybe using Visual/Android Studio might help you along the way because of it's ease of use.)

If this issue isn't present when you just create a new flutter project (without importing any of your own files), then a possible solution would be to only import the `lib` folder from your old project files into the new project. And add the required dependencies into `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: This happens for old and new project as well. 
Can not debug as the the app does not start, there is no code to break. 
The app does not start.

Comment: Does this also happen when you're creating a project within Android Studio?

Comment: I am not using android studio and I do not wish to use it. Too heavy. But yeah, just tried. The same. 
What should be the difference in using android studio?